# when sharing a redirect url (response code 302) on linkedin, shared content has the redirected url (response code- 200)

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-gem

From my app I want to share contents on linkedin with a redirect url this is because when request comes from linkedinbot I want it to redirect to a different page from where it can gets all the meta tags, but if it comes from browser I want to show a different page(an iframe) for users.
For example:-
I want to share the below link "https://example.com/something/1000/redirect" after sharing the above link on linkedin the content have the following href "https://example.com/something/1000/social" which I don't want instead I want the same redirect url as  href on the content.

**Everything is working fine for facebook and twitter**

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you do not want to do any type of redirecting for search engines, or they may mistinterpret your redirection as abuse.  Take a look at the [**Google Ads Policy**](https://support.google.com/adspolicy/answer/6020954?hl=en)...

> The following is not allowed:
>
> Not allowed Engaging in practices that attempt to circumvent or interfere with Google's advertising systems and processes
>
> Example 1: **Cloaking (showing different content to certain users, including Google, than to other users)**...

So, you may have metadata stored in `og:` tags, `oEmbed` pages, `rdf` format, `dc:` dublin core tags, or actually plain simple metadata HTML tags.

Why would you want to show one set of this information to the user and another set to the search engine?  What harm does it do to have the user see what the search engine sees, and vice versa?